# How to log all requests and responses between my application and Facebook with Spring Social?

Tags: java, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I use spring-social-facebook library to let user sign in to my application via Facebook and to get some basic information about the user. Looks like spring-social-facebook logs only responses with error.

The question is:

- Is there a way to log all requests and responses between my app and Facebook with spring-social-facebook library?

I add Facebook ConnectionFactory in SocialConfigurer implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfiguration implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Value("${facebook.app.id}")
    private String appId;

    @Value("${facebook.app.secret}")
    private String appSecret;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new FacebookConnectionFactoryExt(appId, appSecret));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator);
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is it any longer inside your app? How do you implement that library? Is it possible to use interceptors?

Comment: I updated my question with a code snippet - I add a Facebook ConnectionFactory vis SocialConfigurer#addonnectionFactories and looks like there is no way to add an interceptor.